# How can I type the Multiply symbol (“×“) on iPhone?

Tags: ios, text, internationalization

I was using speech recognition to send a message in WhatsApp, and when I said “multiplied by” this sign appeared:

[image]

I can’t remember seeing this symbol on the default iOS keyboards, so I wonder if there are other ways to input this character (and maybe other characters?) into the phone without using speech recognition.

Comment: People usually use the asterisk * when typing; it probably comes from computer programming where 2*2=4; would be the standard way to write it. 2x2=4; would be confusing, as x wouldn't be defined.

Comment: @Tetsujin I beg to disagree, from a properly typographic perspective the “*” asterisk can be confusing, only programming people could understand why one would use “*”

Answer (score 2):

There is a paid app, called unichar that allows for searching (and input) all of the Unicode characters

If you just need to search (and copy) some Unicode chars, you can use their web app at:
https://unichar.app/web/

Comment: As of now unichar is a "free" app that does offer a keyboard, but the multiply symbol (like all math symbols and many other categories) is locked behind the in-app-purchase for $2.99

Answer (score 1):

For such characters you use an app like Unicode Pad.  Or just copy/paste one from here × into a text replacement on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Emoji keyboard you will find a bold "x" in with all the symbols near the end of the list in iOS.

I have never found one with a long press on any letter or character so perhaps that is the only one available to iPhone users.

Comment: However that does not look like the x shown in the question which looks like a Unicode ×
MULTIPLICATION SIGN
Unicode: U+00D7, UTF-8: C3 97 rather than the emoji ✖️
multiplication symbol
Unicode: U+2716 U+FE0F, UTF-8: E2 9C 96 EF B8 8F (from a Mac not an iPhone)

Comment: Agreed, but that is as close as I could find. Perhaps someone else has a better answer. Time will tell.

Comment: PS there are 3rd party keyboards that have these symbols, one is called "Math Symbols" and is free.

Comment: Obviously not “the only one available to iPhone users” if Speech recognition can produce the character in the question. It would just seem weird that Speech recog. is the only way to use this character.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Simbol](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simbol/id792334901?mt=8&uo=4&at=10l7j8), which is a small free app.

Answer (score 0):

Unless/until Apple deigns to provide a built-in unicode keyboard (as [it does for macOS](https://9to5mac.com/2017/05/04/how-to-use-new-apple-emoji-on-macbook/)), you'll need to use a keyboard provided by a 3rd party app.

The free app [CharMap](https://apps.apple.com/app/id369798229) provides a minimal version of this, where you may have a hard time finding the symbol you're looking for.

[×](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm), for example, is about halfway through the LATIN-1 SUPPLEMENT section, near the end of a group of accented capital letters, not grouped with other mathematical symbols.